# Permission dialog for only microphone in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am building a purely audio function flash as3 app. While I request for permission for microphone usage, it is showing both camera and microphone access request to the user.

Is it possible to show access request dialog for only microphone? Because I don't want my user to think, I am secretly collecting webcam stream along with his audio data.

Comment: Is this for web? AIR apps handle permissions a bit differently and bypasses security. This may or may not help with ACTUALLY accessing only the mic though, but you would at least shield your user from seeing that flash is using the camera

Comment: In the case of AIR desktop app, it doesn't ask for permission for mic at all. Like you asked, yes my question is about AS3 on the web for which the answer below seems to be the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible. [The documentation also implies this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d0f.html):

> When your application calls the Microphone.getMicrophone() method,
>   Flash Player displays the Flash Player Settings dialog box, which
>   prompts the user to either allow or deny Flash Player access to the
>   camera and microphone on the system.

Would be a nice feature though!

Comment: helo @JKillian when i called Microphone.getMicrophone()  in iPhone 5s with os 10.3.3, it throws an error PermissoinError: "Error #3800: This call requires Microphone permission."

Comment: I think in Adobe Air mobile, we have to ask permission by our self.